# Examine if $\phi$ is a homomorphism and determin $\ker \phi$ and $Im \phi$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G=(\mathbb C^*,\cdot), G'=(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$ and $\phi : G\to G'$ be defined by $\phi(z)=|z|, z\in \mathbf C^*$, where $\mathbf C^*=\mathbf C-\{0\}$ and $\mathbf R^+$ is a set of all positive real numbers. Then we have to

1. show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
2. determine $\ker \phi$.
3. determine $Im \phi$

**Solution :**

Let $x,y\in G$. Then $\phi(x)=|x|, \phi(y)=|y|$.
  Now $\phi(xy)=|xy|=|x||y|=\phi(x)\phi(y)$
Hence $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

For the second and third,

$\ker\phi=\{x\in G: \phi(x)=0\}$ and $Im \phi=\{ \phi(x)\in G': x\in G\}$. How can I determine $\ker\phi$ and $Im \phi$.

Comment: actually $0$ is not the identity element in $R^*$. It's $1$

Comment: so by definition $\operatorname{Ker}\phi$ is the unit circle

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the kernel of ring homomorphisms. But $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi) = \{x \in G : \phi(x) = e_{G'}\}$, where $e_{G'} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity element in $\Bbb R^*$ is $1$ and not $0$ so the kernel is $$ \{x\in G: \phi(x)=1\}  = \{z \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0\} \ \mid \ |z| = 1 \} $$

This set can either be described as all elements on the unit circle on the complex plane or as the set of all $\{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \ \mid \  \theta \in \Bbb R\}$.

As for the image of $\phi$ notice that any positve element in $ \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} $ is also an element in $ \Bbb C \setminus \{0\} $ and so you should be able to see that this map is onto $(0 , \infty)$.